# Can I do this with regex?

Tags: c++, regex

I need a rule that regex or similar that can be used to parse any given input string containing space delimited words to create a usually longer output string where certain parts get expanded according to certain conditions. I could create code to do this from scratch but I was wondering if I might not need to as this would be not a trivial as it may seem.

In the following example I will use 'a b c etc...' to represent words, this could just as easily be 'cake 14 h etc...' for example however 'a b c etc...' are easier to use to describe how the rule should work. I also use the special characters {, }, [, | and ]. In doing so I am not refering to regex meanings these characters may have.

I'm also going to include line breaks that shouldn't exist in the examples to make things more readable.

The rule would specify that everything inside {} enclosures that occur in the input string wouldn't appear as is in the output string. The contents of a {} would instead occur in the same place but repeated a number of times defined by it's [] enclosures.

1.

Note that 'b' and 'c' are separated with '|'.

```
{a [b | c]}
```

should become:

```
a b
a c
```

2.

Note that 'b' and 'c' are together and separate from 'd'. The {} enclosure contains two []'s, The first containing two elements and the 2nd with 3 elements making 6 in total.

```
{[a b | c][d | e | f]}
```

should become:

```
a b d
a b e
a b f
c d
c e
c f
```

3.

And now for a more involved example.

```
{a [b c | d] e f [g | h | i]} j
```

should become:

```
a b c e f g
a b c e f h
a b c e f i
a d e f g
a d e f h
a d e f i
j
```

without the line breaks such that it should read:

```
a b c e f g a b c e f h a b c e f i a d e f g a d e f h a d e f i j
```

Here are two more concrete examples from DR Seuss with line breaks added to make things easier to read, the 2nd example is edited significantly from the original text:

input:

```
{I do not like [them in a box | them with a fox | them in a house
| them with a mouse | them here or there | them anywhere | green
eggs and ham | them, Sam-I-am].}
```

output:

```
I do not like them in a box.
I do not like them with a fox.
I do not like them in a house.
I do mot like them with a mouse.
I do not like them here or there.
I do not like them anywhere.
I do not like green eggs and ham.
I do not like them, Sam-I-am.
```

input:

```
{[Would | could] you} ? {Would you [like | eat] them
[in a house | with a mouse]?}
```

output:

```
Would you, could you?

Would you like them in a house?
Would you like them with a mouse?

Would you eat them in a house?
Would you eat them with a mouse?
```

Ideally the {} enclosures should be able to stack. None of these examples have shown stacking {} enclosures.

I can already reference individual words from their number (1st, 2nd etc...) or other label, this is easier than for example looking up individual letters some offset into the whole input due to how I am storing the text.

Comment: just to clarify, the actual string will look (verbatim) similar to {a [b c | d] e f [g | h | i]} j ? Just because the pipes etc do seem to tally with their regex meanings, according the output you've given.

Comment: The letters 'a, b, c etc...' refer to words (seqences of characters separated by spaces). The {, }, [, | and ] refer to special syntax I have defined which describe what to do, exist in the input, won't exist in the output and probbably don't correlate to special regex symbols.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do such thing with regular expressions. Regex are used to match a specified pattern in a given string. To generate a list of symbols, you need something like `list comprehensions` or `permutations` (those are just keywords to look for).

Comment: It's sort of like compression, {a [b c | d] e f [g | h | i]} j describes a b c e f g a b c e f h a b c e f i a d e f g a d e f h a d e f i j.

Comment: The keywords 'list', 'comprehensions' and 'permutations' are part of the regex syntax?

Comment: I've looked up permutations and it seems it can't achieve this.

Comment: Re "Ideally the {} enclosures should be able to stack.": You can't do that with (true) regular expressions.  I think the rest of what you want can be approximated with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is probbably not helpfull, others may be helpfull but most of the work would still need to be done yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [Boost.Spirit.Qi](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi.html). As far as I see it, you can parse the expression and represent it as a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), such as this (just the part in the curly braces):

```
           start
             |
             a
            / \
           /   \
         b c    d
           \   /
            \ /
             e
             |
             f
            /|\
           / | \
          g  h  i
           \ | /
            \|/
           stop
```

Then you just have to generate each possible path through that DAG.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that boost's QI parser uses all sorts of C++ code as opposed to a string to define its parsing rule and that its functionality overlaps a little with stringstream?

Comment: It is a parser framework that is designed to enable the specification of grammars in BNF as native C++ code. It does not overlap with stringstream.

Comment: The first example in warming up is something I use stringstream to do. It looks good but potentially almost as complex as writing it myself. Including learning the syntax of QI then probbably more complex.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I get what you mean now. I have each word sepratly referenceable already. QI using my brackets information give me the input in the form of your verry nice digram above and then I could do the rest of the stuff myself such as finding all combinations and producing the output. I think given this that I would probbably not use QI and just do it all myself.

Answer (score 0):

if you were using the [Oniguruma](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/) library you can use named captures like this:

```
^\{(?<a>\w+)\s+\[(?<b>\w+)\s+
(?<c>\w+)\s+
\|\s+
(?<d>\w+)\]\s+
(?<e>\w+)\s+
(?<f>\w+)\s+
\[(?<g>\w+)\s+
\|\s+
(?<h>\w+)\s+
\|\s+
(?<i>\w+)\]\}\s+
(?<j>\w+)\s*$
```

it might work?

---

I don't use C++, but I use Ruby and that uses the Oniguruma regex library. Here is how I would use the above regex in Ruby (from the Interactive Ruby Shell "irb"):

```
s = "{let [them all | eat] as much [cake | as | they]} want"
r = %r!
^\{(?<a>\w+)\s+\[(?<b>\w+)\s+
(?<c>\w+)\s+
\|\s+
(?<d>\w+)\]\s+
(?<e>\w+)\s+
(?<f>\w+)\s+
\[(?<g>\w+)\s+
\|\s+
(?<h>\w+)\s+
\|\s+
(?<i>\w+)\]\}\s+
(?<j>\w+)\s*$
!x

m = r.match s
=> #<MatchData "{let [them all | eat] as much [cake | as | they]} want" a:"let" b:"them" c:"all" d:"eat" e:"as" f:"much" g:"cake" h:"as" i:"they" j:"want">
m[:j]
=> "want"
m[:b]
=> "them"
```

Hope that helps. I also tweaked/fixed? the above regex a little.

---

```
m[:a] + " " + m[:b]
=> "let them"

m[0]
=> "{let [them all | eat] as much [cake | as | they]} want"
```

so now you can manipulate the results however you like. Alternatively, numbered captures still work:

```
m[1] + " " + m[2]
=> "let them"
```

Comment: Does Oniguruma use the regex syntax or it's own? Also I cant hard code 'a', 'b' etc... into the parsing rule, the letters represent any words, I've used 'a', 'b' etc... instead of for example 'w' for word so that I can show how the result correlates to the input.

Comment: Oniguruma uses regex syntax. The a,b,c you see are names for the captures, so that you can then refer to them later, the \w+ captures the actual word, like variable naming. You could refer to them however you like e.g (?<first_word>\w+)\s+(?<second_word>\w+)...

Comment: Thanks for the time. I appreciate it :¬) I don't know regex, would have to learn it's syntax for this task if I used it. It looks like you have now commented out the top part of the regex code and simplfied it into one line. It appears to label the words with letters so that I can look up a word using it's letter, this is not usefull. I already have a way to look up words using there number, 1 for the first, 2 for the 2nd etc...

Comment: What I need is more like m[:[]0] => "them all", "eat". m[:[]1] => "cake", "as", "they". m[:{}0] => "let them all as much cake", "let them all as much as", "let them all as much they", "let eat as much cake", "let eat as much as", "let eat as much they". m[:all] => "let them all as much cake let them all as much as let them all as much they let eat as much cake let eat as much as let eat as much they want". Only I don't need the intermediate steps like m[:[]1].

Comment: those weren't comments, irb added those in to signify newlines, so I've removed them now, sorry for the confusion. You don't have to use named capture, you could just use captures with numbers to signify position, but when you have a lot of captures then giving them names can make things a lot easier.

Comment: If this string ^\{(?<a>\w+)\s+\[(?<b>\w+)\s+ etc... is the rule then I would have to write some code to generate the rule, as it seems to refer explicitly to the labels you are describing 'a' (the first word), 'b' (the 2nd word) etc... in some context involving the {, }, [, |, ] symbols that is always the same, as in it looks like your rule means that there must be of the same number and in the specific places reguardless of the input string. I'm updating the question with some more concrete examples.

Comment: Does your example rule demonstrate named capture or does it demonstrate parsing as described in the question? Have I described clearly with my new examples in the question how the parsing should work?

Comment: Yeah I understand now, regex is just like a really fancy search, it dosn't do what I want. I've already implemented the part regex would be helpfull for.

Comment: yes, those examples are helpful. I agree with @Adrian McCarthy above, that regex will do _most_ of what you want, and you could code the bits inbetween. It is probably a lot of work to re-implement when there are so many good regex libs out there. What I really think you need is a full on parser, one like Alex from the Haskell language, otherwise you're either reinventing the wheel _or_ you're going to contribute a new parsing library to C++ :) http://www.haskell.org/alex/doc/html/introduction.html